# Qt сокет и прием данных, перевед с ASCII в символы

Tags: qt

На сокет передаю данные, числа, но вместо них приходят их коды.

Например число 450, его код 52 53 48 .

Как мне преобразовать этот код в строку типа String, или в число int, что бы с ним можно было работать дальше?

Код приема сокета:

```
 QByteArray arr =  socket->readAll();
    foreach(QTcpSocket *socket, sockets) { 

        if (socket->state() == QTcpSocket::ConnectedState)

            socket->write(arr);

    }
```

Прием данных с wifi на сокет идет, шлю с модуля esp8266. Но в arr, после приема, коды символов.

Comment: Может быть покажете свой код?

Comment: [QString::fromUtf8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8-1), например. И [QString::toInt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt)

Comment: Добавил исходный код